# What is the letter's meaning in non focused tabs

Tags: gvim, plugin-airline

I am wondering what the letters before the filename in a non focused tab stands for. 
In the example in the picture `c/s/s/`.

[image]

Comment: The first letters of the path components of the file loaded in that tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a short-hand describing your path.
I.e. if you path was:

```
Some/Long/Path/file.txt
```

The resulting tab would end up looking like:

```
S/L/P/file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense! Didn't thought of that! Is there a way to disable it? Or enable it only if there are two files with the same name?

Comment: Is this airline? `:h airline` and search for formatter

Comment: @Mark, not that I know of. Sorry.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I think I have to dig deeper into the airline configuration - thanks for the help

Comment: This is available by default.